# How Corda replace the current data consistency used in financial industry

Tags: blockchain, corda

> If we use corda in banking industry. How its work. For example,Corda
>   is a Distributed Ledger Technology and based on peer to peer
>   connection, for example three bank A, B and C. If bank A send money to
>   bank B then only acknowledgement will done between these to C wont be
>   aware of it despite C has peer to peer connections with both A and B,
>   this is what corda for according to my understanding.
>
> My question is, did all the bank need to have Corda and what if other
>   banks not have it. Another question is this data consistency is I
>   think followed by all banks then why should they use corda. How can we
>   differentiate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corda's core concept is that only the parties who are part of that particular transaction will store it and see it.
- Yes, every bank should have that corda Dapp installed to take part in it.
- Corda facilitates banks to maintains the privacy of their data (although with some centralisation like notary node) but it facilitates auditing, provenance and inter-bank transfer smoothly by using DLT, that is very much needed in this space.

Comment: Thanks James for clearing my doubt, Actually I'm a ethereum solidity man and currently starting with corda, really appreciate you answer.

Comment: Welcome Vinay :)